# SharePoint 2016 Survey answers empty after migration

Tags: 2016, survey

After migrating a survey (2010 to 2016) responses from January through April contain no data.  It reads that the survey was complete by specific users but no data carried over so all choice fields and comments fields are empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How did you migrate the data?  Using the database attach method or with a third party tool?  I've seen this behavior before when using tools like Content Matrix or ShareGate, the only way to troubleshoot is to look at the migration error logs.

Comment: Third party tool.  It turns out the survey was changed after its initial creation and therefore the data never carried over for the changed questions. Thanks!